# Can't define method inside my object

Tags: javascript

I want to define a method inside my object.
Here's how i did it -

```
var vcar
{
    displayMsg: function(msg) {
    //code
    }
}
```

Javascript console says -
uncaught syntaxError: unexpected token {

Can you let me know what is wrong in my code ?

Thanks,

Comment: you left out the assignment token.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `=` sign.

```
var vcar =
{
    displayMsg: function(msg) {
    //code
    }
}
```